# How to run Run command through Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-active-directory, windows-10, azure-powershell

I want to enroll users to Azure AD using the link ms-device-enrollment:?mode=mdm, my question is how can I use this script through powershell so the user just need to run script and enrolment prompt will appear.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXD9O.jpg)

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you follow the guidance here when posting a question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's just a one line question with attached image on it.

Comment: I found the answer Start-Process ms-device-enrollment:?mode=mdm save this file as .ps1

Comment: You have found the solution right? Can you add an answer so that it can help more people?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer Start-Process ms-device-enrollment:?mode=mdm save this file as .ps1